# clj-xpath for xml with simple and nested tags

Tags: xml, xpath, clojure

I have function (contents-only) that extracts contents from xml using clj-xpath library.

```
(ns example
(:use  [clj-xpath.core]))

 (def data-url
"http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=4H4Vff4PdrTGp3vV&keywords=music&location=New+York&date=Future")

(defn xml-data [url] (slurp url))

(defn defxmldoc [url]
      (xml->doc (xml-data url)))

(defn contents-only [url root-tag tags] 
 (vec(map(fn [item]
         (into {}
              (map (fn [tag]
                     [tag ($x:text (str "./" (name tag))item)])tags)))
      (take 5 ($x root-tag (defxmldoc url))))))
```

The function call looks like this

```
(contents-only data-url "/search/events/event" [:title :url])
```

It works fine with not-nested tags, when I try to extract text from a nested tag ie.

```
<performers>
 <performer>
   <id>P0-001-000009049-1</id>
    <url>...</url>
    <name>Lindsey Buckingham</name>
    <short_bio>Rock</short_bio>
    <creator>TomAzoff</creator>
    <linker>evdb</linker>
</performer>
```

Function call looks like this

```
(contents-only data-url "/search/events/event" [:title :url :name])
```

I get RuntimeException Error, more (or less) than 1 result (0) from xml({:children...) for xpath(./name)  clj-xpath.core/throwf (core.clj:26)

How to change my contents-only function, so I can pass a nested tag as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way : change `"./"` to `".//"` in `contents-only` function.

```
user> (first (contents-only data-url "/search/events/event" [:title :id :name]))
{:title "Legally Blonde the Musical", :id "P0-001-000351944-7", :name "Legally Blonde The Musical"}
user>
```

As explained in [xpath documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), `.//name` will select all nodes `name` starting from the current node, wherever in the hierarchy.

If `name` is not unique, it may not be what you want, and one way is to be explicit in the path you specify, e.g.

```
(contents-only data-url "/search/events/event"
                [[:title]
                 [:performers :performer :id]
                 [:performers :performer :name]])
```

and to have some helper functions like :

```
(defn build-path
  ([sep kys] (build-path nil sep kys))
  ([root sep kys]
   (->> kys (map name) (interpose sep) 
        (concat (when root (list root sep))) (apply str))))

(defn path
  "build a path from a collection"
  [t]
  (build-path "." \/ t))

user> (path [:performers :performer :id])
"./performers/performer/id"

(defn path-key
  "Transform [:a :b :c] into :a-b-c"
  [t]
  (->> t (build-path \-) keyword))

user> (path-key [:performers :performer :id])
:performers-performer-id
```

Then the `contents-only` becomes :

```
(defn contents-only2 [url root-tag tags]
  (vec (map(fn [item]
             (into {}
                   (map (fn [tag]
                          [(path-key tag) ($x:text (path tag) item)])
                        tags)))
           (take 5 ($x root-tag (defxmldoc url))))))
```

and the result :

```
user> (first (contents-only2 data-url "/search/events/event"
                      [[:title]
                       [:performers :performer :id]
                       [:performers :performer :name]]))
{:title "Legally Blonde the Musical", :performers-performer-id "P0-001-000351944-7", :performers-performer-name "Legally Blonde The Musical"}
user>
```

Comment: When I change "./" to ".//" the fn doesn't work, but the new contents-extract works just fine, thanks a lot